# Azure Bicep - Best practice with regards to noisy what-if output

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, infrastructure-as-code

I am creating a deployment on Azure from scratch consisting of various resources, e.g., Application Gateway, AKS cluster, Managed Identities. When checking `az what-if` after deploying, I can see some unexpected noise. I know that the team is working on eliminating as much noise as they can from the `what-if` output, but what is good practice with regards to this in the mean time?

- replicate the changes in the template, such that they don't appear?
- keep track of the previous 'what-if' output, then compare with the next one to see what *actually* changed?
- deploy in stages, such that the noisy part can be separated from the clean part?
- ...

I spotted various types of noise, easy or difficult to deal with:

1. **default properties** that were not specified in the template. For example, `properties.networkProfile.ipFamilies == 'IPv4` for a managedCluster. I could add this in the template to make it more complete, which would eliminate the noise.
2. **external influences** such as vnet peerings made by external parties. When outside parties peer with my `vnet`, it changes its definition too, which then pops up as noise (`properties.virtualNetworkPeerings`). When re-applying, as far as I understood, it fortunately doesn't eliminate these peerings. However, it would be nice to know *when* it doesn't overwrite such changes. Is this described somewhere?
3. **references** such as `properties.principalId:   "a09185a3d" => "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', parameters('test-mi')), '2018-11-30').principalId]"`. I've seen this described as a bug/issue on the tracker, yet to be resolved.
4. **bidirectional** information (don't have an example at hand), like allowing a resource access to the vnet, which would modify the vnet but would also show a reference to the vnet in the resource. This is superfluous information, and adding it to the template to make sure the `what-if` remains clean seems wrong.

So, generally speaking, I'm looking for some tips and tricks to get the cleanest workflow possible. Having proper feedback on the upcoming changes on a template is crucial to prevent mistakes.

Comment: I'd encourage you to report any noise you find on the what-if repo over on GitHub
https://github.com/Azure/arm-template-whatif/labels/noise